# Search engine page creating

Tags: seo, search-engine

I noted that Google use web page content when they `index` pages for **SEO** purposes. Therefore, what I did was I created the web pages and I used lot of keyword on the web pages. Then I applied the background color to the above keywords to show users.

Question is do they block this kind of pages?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search Engine Optimization (SEO) is something you really need an expert for these days.  The days of having some keywords and meta-data only have long gone, so you need to keep up to date with current SEO tricks to get your site up the **Google** ranking.  You can also check the [Alexa rankings](http://www.alexa.com/) for your website.

Take a look at the SEO guidelines from Google [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35291?hl=en)

Take a look at some pointers [here](http://www.seomark.co.uk/small-business-seo-tips/) and [here](http://raventools.com/blog/48-tips-for-seo-newbies/), but you really need to invest some time and research into the best practices.

You should also make your site as accessible as possible, this will make the site easier to **spider**, there are some [tools here](http://www.w3.org/WAI/RC/tools/complete) to look at and there's a [site here](http://achecker.ca/checker/index.php) you can use.

Comment: does this mean, what I did is wrong? Thanks for the link. I wil continue reading them

Comment: @wordpressm, I'm not suggesting what you did is wrong, I'm just highlighting that there's a lot of factors to making a page/site SEO friendly.  Google will usually select keywords based on how frequent they are in the text, I don't think a background colour will help here.

Comment: Thanks christinadev. I did to hide keywords from users.